# Memory Requirements for Hyper-V Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, virtual-machine

I am attempting to create a virtual machine for the first time using the Hyper-V Quick Create Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (Windows 10 version 1709) and it is saying that, "We recommend having at least 34.82 GB of free space for this image. The destination drive (C:) only has 31.24 GB of free space." How much memory does a VM actually require to run smoothly whether on Hyper-V or any other platform/system etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a memory warning. This is a warning about your harddisk being full and having less space than recommended. This said a VM can be as small as 10GB or less. It depends on what OS you are trying to install.

Comment: On windows, 31.24 GB will work? Also will the VM occupy a certain amount of space permanently or how does that work?

Comment: Sorry Lou this is going really offtopic and really 101 level for stackoverflow. I suggest you this reading instead: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/overview/what-is-a-virtual-machine/

Comment: Btw hdd requirements for a vm are permanent. Cpu and ram are variable (ram only with balooning) and are freed when the vm is shut down.